# How to set up sites/applications to share same Application Pool on Windows Azure

Tags: iis, azure, application-pool, azure-web-roles

I'm hosting web site and web service in same Web Role using Windows Azure. The problem is that for each site/application there is created a separate application pool on IIS.
Is there any way to make all of them share one application pool?

Here is my actual csdef for which I have three different application pools in IIS (1x for `Virtual Application`, 1x for site `AppWS` and 1x for site `Web`)

```
<WebRole name="Orchard.Azure.Web" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="VAppWS" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\AppWS" />
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Binding80" endpointName="Endpoint80" />
      <Binding name="Binding443" endpointName="Endpoint443" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="AppWS" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\AppWS">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Binding444" endpointName="Endpoint444" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint80" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint443" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="ssl.root" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint444" protocol="https" port="444" certificate="ssl.ws" />
</Endpoints>
...
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to share an app pool?

Comment: Yes, each application pool allocates memory. I tested that and in my case it is about 100MB per app pool. My resources are very limited and this seems to be a waste. (In fact they host the same app.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to specify the apppool, so you have to run some code after IISConfigurator has done its job and reassign appools.
You could use Azure startup task, but unfortunately it runs too early - before IISconfigurator.

Take a look at this for a workaround: http://mvolo.com/configure-iis-websites-windows-azure-startup-tasks-appcmd/

He creates a special async task that runs the init commands after IISConfigurator.
The init commands could be something like this - it assigns all app pools to a newly created one:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /name:MyApplicationPool /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list app /xml | %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app /in /applicationPool:MyApplicationPool
```

Another approach could be to do the reassigning in a special webapp using Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly.

Take a look at this for an example: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/